# Erro import import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.User

Tags: java, eclipse, framework, demoiselle, interface

Erro ao importar a interface `User`:

```
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.User;
```

Versão do demoiselle utilizada: 2.5.0-RC1

De acordo com o GrepCode, na versão 2.5.0-BETA2, esta interface existia (http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle/demoiselle-core/2.5.0-BETA2/br/gov/frameworkdemoiselle/security/User.java?av=f), porém a partir da 2.5.0-BETA3 em diante, ela desapareceu (http://grepcode.com/project/repo1.maven.org/maven2/br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle/demoiselle-core/).

Alguém sabe qual a interface que substitui a 'User' ?

Estou implementando a interface `Authenticator`:

```
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.Authenticator;
import br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.security.User;

public class Autenticador implements Authenticator {
    ...
    @Override
    public User getUser() {
        return new User() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void setAttribute(Object arg0, Object arg1) {

            }

            @Override
            public String getId() {
                return "usuario X";
            }

            @Override
            public Object getAttribute(Object arg0) {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Essa interface foi descontinuada e ao invés dela recomendamos o uso do java.security.Principal que torna a solução mais compatível com outros padrões do Java como o JAAS por exemplo.

Lembrando que o Demoiselle 2.5 ainda não está na versão final, enquanto isso estamos fazendo testes na aplicação de exemplo:  https://github.com/demoiselle/laboratory/tree/master/estacionamento/v25X

ex:

....

```
@Override
public  Principal getUser() {

    if (authenticated) {

        return new Principal() {

            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return credentials.getUsername();
            }

        };
    }else{
        return null;
    }

}

@Override
public void unauthenticate() throws Exception {
    credentials.clear();
    authenticated = false;
}
```

Comment: A versão 2.5.0 foi lançada.